# How to handle an exception from MethodInvokingFactoryObject Spring.NET?

Tags: spring.net

I have `Spring.Configuration` like that:

```xml
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
    <!-- Create SQLite connection -->
    <object id="SqlConnection" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="Data Source=MyDatabase.db"/>
    </object>
    <!-- Open connection -->
    <object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.MethodInvokingFactoryObject, Spring.Core">
        <property name="TargetObject">
            <ref local="SqlConnection" />
        </property>
        <property name="TargetMethod" value="Open"/>
    </object>
</objects>
```

So how do I handle an exception from the method `Open()` if this throws since `MethodInvokingFactoryObject` is created and invoked?

Comment: Are you using the `MethodInvokingFactoryObject` only to call an initialization method? Please give a bit more context to your question, e.g. a small program.